# Dojo bar menu is stack on selected state

Tags: javascript, dojo

Does anyone know how  to  programmatically unselect dojo  dijit.MenuBarItem. The problem is that when I select one of the items on the dijit.MenuBar the dialog pops up(I can see the bar menu item getting deselected), the user enters info and closes the dialog, but the bar menu item gets  selected again and stays selected all the time. I have tried:

```
dijit.byId("navMenu")._markInactive();  
dijit.byId("navMenu").isActive = false;
```

or

```
dijit.byId("transId")._markInactive();
dijit.byId("transId").isActive = false;
```

but it does not do it.
Any other suggestions please, thanks

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id='barPane'data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="padding:0px;">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuBar" id="navMenu">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuBarItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:uploadAndClearDialog">Upload</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuBarItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:exportCsv">Download</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuBarItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:showTranslateDialog" id="transId">Translate</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the MenuBarItem.  In the debugging console I can call _setSelected(false) on the item itself and have it deselect, but this doe not work if I try putting it in code after a show() call on a dialog.  (Yes, debugger indicates the dialog has closed once I try _setSelected(false). )  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the statement "_setSelected(false)" at the end of the process just before the end and it worked perfectly.

For example:

```
function yourFnt() {
    // Close dialog
    dijit.byId('yourDlg').onCancel();

    require(["dojo/request","dojo/domReady!" ],
    function(request) {
        var vURL = "yourserviceURL"
        var deferred = request.get(vURL, {
                        handleAs : "json"
                    });
        deferred.then(function(response) {
            ...
            ...
            // Unselect menuitem
            dijit.byId("yourMenuItem")._setSelected(false);
            });
        });
}
```